# is there a way to fix access blocked clerk request does not comply with google policy

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, google-oauth, clerk

I'm integrating clerk authentication  to allow users to sign up using google auth in my expo react native application , but i get a error that clerk request does not comply with google policy
Here is my code

```
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession()


enum Strategy {
    Google = 'oauth_google',
    Apple = 'oauth_apple',
    Facebook = 'oauth_facebook'
}

export default function Page() {
    useWarmUpBrowser();

    const router = useRouter()

    const { startOAuthFlow: appleAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_apple' })
    const { startOAuthFlow: googleAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_google' })
    const { startOAuthFlow: facebookAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_facebook' })


    // function to choose the auth

    const onSelectAuth = async (strategy: Strategy) => {

        // select strategy => create a object with key and value to select each auth using enum

        const selectedAuth = {
            [Strategy.Google]: googleAuth,
            [Strategy.Apple]: appleAuth,
            [Strategy.Facebook]: facebookAuth

        }[strategy];

        try {
            const {createdSessionId , setActive} = await selectedAuth()

            //console.log(createdSessionId , 'session started')

            if(createdSessionId){
                setActive!({session:createdSessionId})
                router.back()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('OAuth error', error)
            
        }

    }


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput autoCapitalize='none' placeholder='email' style={[defaultStyles.inputField, { marginBottom: 30 }]} />
            <TouchableOpacity style={defaultStyles.btn}>
                <Text style={defaultStyles.btnText}>Continue</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.separatorView}>
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    borderBottomColor: '#000',
                    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                }} />

                <Text style={styles.separator}>or</Text>
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    borderBottomColor: '#000',
                    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                }} />

            </View>
            <View style={{ gap: 20 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnOutline}>
                    <Ionicons size={24} name='call-outline' style={defaultStyles.btnIcon} />
                    <Text style={styles.btnOutlineText}>Continue with phone</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onSelectAuth(Strategy.Apple)} style={styles.btnOutline}>
                    <Ionicons size={24} name='md-logo-apple' style={defaultStyles.btnIcon} />
                    <Text style={styles.btnOutlineText}>Continue with Apple</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onSelectAuth(Strategy.Google)} style={styles.btnOutline}>
                    <Ionicons size={24} name='md-logo-google' style={defaultStyles.btnIcon} />
                    <Text style={styles.btnOutlineText}>Continue with google</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onSelectAuth(Strategy.Facebook)} style={styles.btnOutline}>
                    <Ionicons size={24} name='md-logo-facebook' style={defaultStyles.btnIcon} />
                    <Text style={styles.btnOutlineText}>Continue with Facebook</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

on selecting google to sign up, the below error pops up. I have already configured my token from clerks dashboard to facilitate the authentication, but it is still not working .

[image: error message that appears on the android emulator]

Comment: Make sure it opens in the system browser.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo still not working

Comment: Any chance you can give me a [example] your code is giving me a pile of errors when i try to run it.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo  , It's an expo react native project, so I'm using clerk to streamline the sign-up process. on press of the button which should trigger a a pop for Google sign up , from my android emulator the error message that pops up its the  one described above

Comment: Sorry without a working example I cant be much more help. Other than to tell you it needs to open a browser on the users system and it cant be using http it must be https.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thank you! i may send  you  the GitHub link to project

Comment: I would love to help but im not the best at react and im getting hit with lint errors im not sure how to fix.  I may try again tomrrow.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo  Thank youu